# How can i populate the right swreveal view controller with an array of prototype cells created in main.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

Im new to stack overflow and this is my first post so please be patient with me!

I have my sw_rear and sw_front set up and they work perfectly.

However when i tried creating a table view filled with prototype cells for my sw_right linked to an array seperate from the one i have in my sw_rear i found that when i tried swiping or even pushing a button to access the right menu the app crashes without any errors printing to the log.

(i have 2 arrays in 2 seperate swift files rearVc & rightVC linked to 2 seperate tableviews sw_rear & sw_right)

I have searched online for the last week (all my google hyperlinks are purple!!) and cant seem to find an answer at all. I thought that copying this code (found in my rear reveal table vc) into my right table vc would work but it unfortunately does not!

(CODED IN SWIFT, fyi i used a bridging header for swrevealvc as i dont know obj c)

```
import Foundation

class rearTableVC: UITableViewController {

var rearTableArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    rearTableArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rearTableArray.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(rearTableArray[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rearTableArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

as you can see im using "cell.detailTextLabel?.text" so that my customised prototype cells ive built in main.storyboard will be the ones populating my list.

Both are correctly linked to my nav controller as well as other scenes.

I know that part is fine, im just stuck with the code.

In my root view controller im running this code and it works like a charm so no problems there.

```
import Foundation

    class aVC : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var menuButtonLeft: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var menuButtonRight: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    menuButtonLeft.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButtonLeft.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

    menuButtonRight.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButtonRight.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and i am more then willing to add any more info that is needed!!

Thanks.

(sorry i cant add pictures)

Comment: You wrote you got no debug output after fail. What is the line marked red when crashed? What it contains?

Comment: Have you set up and named all prototype cells in Storyboard as 'a', 'b' ... 'f'?

Comment: At SO, we don't put "Solved" in the title. We post an answer to our own question so that it helps people later.

Comment: Please don't include the solution in your *question* and don't add "solved" either. You can post your own *answer* instead, it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @pedrouan check my edit i found a solution, thanks for your answer though!!

Comment: sorry for that ill change it now still new to stack overflow!!

Comment: @YUragun You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Hi after beating around the bush for hours i finally found a solution, a very very excruciatingly simple solution.
In the SWRevealViewController.m three important parts are missing. I don't know obj-c at all but figured that these lines were missing code for the rightViewController so after adding them everything worked!

```
- (id)init
{
return [self initWithRearViewController:nil frontViewController:nil rightViewController:nil];
}

 - (id)initWithRearViewController:(UIViewController *)rearViewController frontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController rightViewController:(UIViewController *)rightViewController;
{
self = [super init];
if ( self )
{
    [self _initDefaultProperties];
    [self     _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRearController withViewController:rearViewController animated:NO];
    [self    _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceFrontController withViewController:frontViewController animated:NO];
    [self _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRightController withViewController:rightViewController animated:NO];
}
```

All i added was the

```
return [self initWithRearViewController:nil frontViewController:nil rightViewController:nil];
```

and

```
rightViewController:(UIViewController *)rightViewController;
```

and

```
_performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRightController withViewController:rightViewController animated:NO];
```

lines

EDIT 2 (requested info)

```
#pragma mark - Init

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if ( self )
{
    [self _initDefaultProperties];
}    
return self;
}


- (id)init
{
return [self initWithRearViewController:nil frontViewController:nil rightViewController:nil];
}


- (id)initWithRearViewController:(UIViewController *)rearViewController frontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController rightViewController:(UIViewController *)rightViewController;
{
self = [super init];
if ( self )
{
    [self _initDefaultProperties];
    [self     _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRearController withViewController:rearViewController animated:NO];
    [self _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceFrontController withViewController:frontViewController animated:NO];
    [self _performTransitionOperation:SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRightController withViewController:rightViewController animated:NO];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: @pedrouan sure thing adding now

Comment: @pedrouan added extra info :)